# Java NIO non-blocking mode vs node.js asynchronous operation

Tags: java, multithreading, node.js, asynchronous, nio

I have not gone through the code detail of node.js .

But, going through some research about thread in  Node.js, I found that it has single thread for accepting connection from multiple clients.

When connected with client it fires connection events and listens for another client and work fully in asynchronous style  and  rest operation of client  request  is performed from thread pool and result is sent back to main thread(Thread that accepts connection) via callback.

Like wise in Java NIO also ServerSocketChannel,SocketChannel can be set in  non-blocking mode and with selector single thread can  monitor multiple channels. So, using NIO ServerSocketChannel,SocketChannel also from single thread the connection can be managed asynchronously for multiple clients

So, is the NIO's non-blocking mode and  node.js asynchronous with single thread  follows the same pattern for concept of single thread? As both say they perform on single thread.

Comment: It is common misconception to assume async and non-blocking are similar patterns. Node.js also has non-blocking socket operations. So yes, both frameworks have non-blocking IO allowing them to handle multiple several conenctions from single thread.

Answer (score 6):

Asynchrony in general, and NIO in particular, are not necessarily backed by single thread, they can be supported by multiple threads to increase performance. However, multithreading requires additional synchronization (not complex, but accurate). Since javascript lacks synchronization utilities, Node.js has to use single thread. Java asynchronous frameworks can use multiple threads.

Apendix

Why is Node.js single-threaded by design? From [Understanding Node.js](http://debuggable.com/posts/understanding-node-js:4bd98440-45e4-4a9a-8ef7-0f7ecbdd56cb):

> "So I don't have to worry about code accessing the same data
> structures at the same time?"
>
> You got it! That's the entire beauty of JavaScripts
> single-threaded/event loop design!

So the most likely cause of single-threaded design is to please javascript programmers, which, en masse, are not familiar with synchronization concepts.

Comment: Node.js uses single thread, so it doesn't need synchronization primitives, not the other way around

Comment: you said the reason node.js is singlethreaded is that javascript lacks synchronization utilities. That's not true — node.js is singlethreaded by design, so it doesn't NEED them. If they were needed, they could be implemented, there is nothing about javascript that can prevent it

Answer (score 3):

No. Non-blocking means that the operations don't block, and they tell you what they did. Asynchronous means they the operations continue in parallel and call you back when they finish. They are completely different programming paradigms.

Comment: I wrote this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660710/if-a-web-server-is-non-blocking-does-this-mean-it-is-handling-io-the-same-as-no and wondered if you think I am confusing the same things.

Comment: @johhny Yes you are.